# Ionic form calls ngOnInit multiple times

Tags: angular, forms, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, ngoninit

I have a form that displays existing data from Firestore and then upon on change the data is updated. The problem is that the ngOnInit seems to being called multiple times, then the saveInspectionChanges() function is called. I am not sure why these functions are being activated when there is no change occurring on the page yet. When the form is opened, the fields blink continually and then when the form is closed and null data is saved.

**detail.page.ts**

```
  public inspectionID: string = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
  public inspection: any;
  public Customer: any;
  public Site: any;
  public Tank: any;

  inspectionDetailsForm: FormGroup;

  public Users: any;

  constructor(
    private firestoreService: FirestoreService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private alertController: AlertController,
    private router: Router,
    formBuilder: FormBuilder, public firestore: AngularFirestore,
  ) {
    this.inspectionDetailsForm = formBuilder.group({
      Date: [''],
      InspectionType: [''],
      Status: [''],
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.inspection = this.firestoreService.getInspectionDetail(this.inspectionID).valueChanges();
    this.inspection.subscribe(inspection => {
      this.inspectionDetailsForm.patchValue(inspection);
    });
  }

  updateInspection(data: any) {
    return this.firestore.collection('inspectionList').doc(this.inspectionID)
      .update(data);
  }

  saveInspectionChanges() {
    if (this.inspectionDetailsForm.status !== 'VALID') {
      console.log('form is not valid, cannot save to database');
      return;
    }
    console.log('form is valid, saving to database');
    const data = this.inspectionDetailsForm.value;
    this.updateInspection(data);
  }
```

**detail.page.html**

```
<ion-content>
  <form [formGroup]="inspectionDetailsForm" novalidate>
    <ion-list lines="full" class="ion-no-margin ion-no-padding">
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label position="stacked">Date</ion-label>
          <ion-input formControlName="Date" type="date"></ion-input>  
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label position="stacked">Inspection Type</ion-label>
          <ion-select formControlName="InspectionType" okText="OK" cancelText="Dismiss" (ionChange)="saveInspectionChanges()">
            <ion-select-option value="API 653 Internal">API 653 Internal</ion-select-option>
            <ion-select-option value="API 653 External">API 653 External</ion-select-option>
            <ion-select-option value="STI-SP001">STI SP-001</ion-select-option>
          </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label position="stacked">Status</ion-label>
          <ion-select formControlName="Status" okText="OK" cancelText="Dismiss" (ionChange)="saveInspectionChanges()">
            <ion-select-option value="Scheduled">Scheduled</ion-select-option>
            <ion-select-option value="Preliminary Report">Preliminary Report</ion-select-option>
            <ion-select-option value="Report not complete">Report not complete</ion-select-option>
            <ion-select-option value="Report complete">Report complete</ion-select-option>
          </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </form>

</ion-content>
```

**detail.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { DetailPage } from './detail.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DetailPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  declarations: [DetailPage]
})
export class DetailPageModule {}
```

Comment: if ngOnInit is called multiple times, it means your component is loaded multiple times. Can you show the component using the detail component ?

Comment: @Random I added the modules code. Is that what you mean me to show?

Comment: Indeed, so this is a routed component, which should only be once in a page. This component is never called by an other component right ? So you may add log to the constructor instead of ngOnInit. It would confirm the component is instanciated multiple times whereas it should be instanciated only once.

Comment: The page is accessed from a list on tab through     <ion-card *ngFor="let inspection of inspectionList | async" routerLink="/inspectiondetail/{{inspection.id}}">